# Was the Milky Way visible in all its glory in pre-industrial times?

Tags: everyday-life, astronomy

So, this is a bit of a silly question admittedly, but it's something that seems obviously the case, yet we never really acknowledge or make a big deal out of.

Before the industrialisation and all the light pollution that came with it, could any random peasant just step out of their house / village and immediately have a night sky that we could only see in the Atacama desert today? Was this much more impressive and colorful firmament simply just a part of everyday life?

Comment: :) Amazingly, "yes!" Hard to imagine, ... :)

Comment: Well, I suspect there were many nights in Europe with clouds in the way. Just altitude alone makes a big difference, as does (non-cloud) water vapor content.

Comment: Sure, the Milky Way was visible, but it likely still wasn't as impressive as in photographs.

Comment: The "light contamination" of many areas today make it much less visible now than then, for most people.

Comment: Hmmph. I had written a good answer and it closed just as I was trying to save it! I do think it has some historical value.

Comment: Of course the answer is yes. There can be no doubt in it. You can see it nowadays only by traveling to a desert or mountains (far from human settlements) or in the open sea in a sailboat (so that you can extinguish all lights). The view is really breathtaking, and it is a pity that most modern people never see it in their life. It is much more exciting than any pictures, and I recommend everyone to try at least once. There is one possible obstacle: weather. So the best place to go is really a desert.

Comment: You can't see the Milky Way when the full moon illuminates the sky. On cloudless moonless nights away from city lights you can see it.

Comment: @Alex : There is another obstacle: moonlight.

Comment: @Michael Hardy: this is correct and good point. But on most nights, Moon is not visible during some part of the night. Full Moon is indeed an obstacnce since it is visible most of the night.